# Calculating the Number of Fish in a Pond After $N$ Days

Tags: probability

I thought of the following question while on holidays at my friend's cottage.

Suppose there is a pond with $N$ fish on the first day.

Each day there is a:

- $p_1$ probability that $n_1$ % of the current population will be added to the pond (i.e. if there are currently 100 fish in the pond
  there is a $p_1$ probability that the population of the pond tomorrow will be 100 + $n_1$*100)
- $p_2$ probability that $n_2$ % of the current population will be removed from the pond (i.e. if there are currently 100 fish in the pond, there is a $p_2$ probability that the population of the pond tomorrow will be 100 - $n_2$*100)

Assume some fixed values of $N$, $n_1$, $n_2$, $p_1$ and $p_2$ : Given this information, in 365 days from now, what is the expected population of the pond?

I understand the there are independent probabilities - so the population of the fish pond on the 365th day will only depend on the population of the 364th day. I think it might be possible to write a recursive formulas of Expected Values to find out how many different pond populations are possible on the 364th day and the probability of obtaining each one of these potential populations - but I am unsure how to do this.

At the moment, I am thinking of writing a Python simulation that will simulate the pond population over 365 days with these rules and record the population on the 365th day ... and then repeat this simulation many times. Finally, I would take the average of all simulations and find out the expected number of fish in the pond on the 365th day. But I was hoping there might be some compact formula to help me with this?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why all the italics?  Let me strongly recommend you rewrite the entire question (context and all) in two (or maximum three) sentences.  It will be excellent training for you, and will garner more help.

Comment: So it is possible (indeed highly likely) that fish will BOTH be added and subtracted on the same day??  How does that work?

Comment: Please state your probabilities as numbers, not percentages.  It saves typing a difficult symbol that needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

What is much easier to calculate is the expected value of the logarithm of the number of fish.  Each day you have a $p_1 \%$ chance the log increases by $\log (1+n_1\%)$ and a $p_2 \%$ chance the log decreases by $\log (1-n_2\%)$.  The expected value of the change in the log is $3.65(p_1 \log (1+n_1\%)-p_2 \log (1-n_2\%))$  You can compute the variance as well from the variance of your one day distribution.

Comment: Here's a well-formed version of the question, which avoids the "add AND subtract" confusion:  Let $n(i)$ denote the number of fish in a pond on day $i$, and $p$ be the probability that $k_1 n(i)$ fish will be added and $1-p$ be the probability that $k_2 n(i)$ will be removed on day $i$.  Given $n(0)$, $p$, $k_1$, and $k_2$, compute the expected value of $n(365)$.   *See how that works?*

Comment: Can you please explain why its 3.65?

Comment: Because I took out the percent sign on the $p$'s

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rough way that I think can be used to solve this problem.

Let's say that:

- $E_t$ is the expected number of fish on the $t$-th day
- $E_{t-1}$ is the expected number of fish on the $t-1$-th day
- $p_3 = 1 - p_1 + p_2$.

Then, we can define:

\begin{align*}
E_t &= [E_{t-1} \times p_3] + p_1[E_{t-1} + n_1 \times E_{t-1}] + p_2[E_{t-1} - n_2 \times E_{t-1}]
\end{align*}

$E_{t-1}$ is common, so we can factor it out:

\begin{align*}
E_t &= E_{t-1} \times [ p_3 + p_1(1+n_1) + p_2(1-n_2)]
\end{align*}

For simplicity, let's define $Z = [ p_3 + p_1(1+n_1) + p_2(1-n_2)] $, thus:

\begin{align*}
E_t &= E_{t-1} \times Z
\end{align*}

We can now recognize a pattern ($E_0$ is the number of fish at the start, $E_1$ is the number of fish on the first day, etc.):

\begin{align*}
E_1 &= E_0 \times Z \\
E_2 &= E_1 \times Z = E_0 \times Z^2 \\
E_3 &= E_2 \times Z = E_0 \times Z^3
\end{align*}

This means that on the 365th day, the Expected Number of fish in the pond will be:

\begin{align*}
E_{365} &= E_{0} \times Z^{365} = E_{0} \times [ p_3 + p_1(1+n_1) + p_2(1-n_2)]^{365}
\end{align*}

Hope this helps!

**Note:** I wonder how we could calculate the variance of $E_t$ ...